# Spring JMS listener - how to read messages based on a condition

Tags: spring, jms, spring-jms

I have configured Spring JMS in my project. 
Now my requirement is that messages are read only when the flag in a properties file in ON.

what are ways to implement this in Spring?

Answer (score 5):

When asking questions like this, it's always best to show your configuration so people can provide a very specific answer.

The general solution is to use the property to set the `autoStartup` property to `false` on the listener container, or listener container factory (if using `@JmsListener` annotations).

Use a property placeholder, e.g. `${should.start}`.